# python: count word tokens in sentence

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm trying to count the number of words in a string. however, i first have to strip some punctuations e.g.

```
line = "i want you , to know , my name . "
```

running

```
en = line.translate(string.maketrans('', ''), '!,.?')
```

produces

```
en = "i want you  to know  my name  "
```

after this, i want to count the number of words in the line. but when i do len(en) I get 30 instead of 7.

Using split on en to tokenize and find the length doesn't work in all cases. e.g.

i tried that it doesn't always work. e.g. consider this string.

```
"i ccc bcc the a of the abc ccc dd on aaa , 28 abc 19 ."
```

en then becomes:

```
"i ccc bcc the a of the abc ccc dd on aaa 28 abc 19 "
```

but len(en) returns 17 and not 15.

can you please help? thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem with `en.split(' ')` is that you have extra whitespace in your string, which gives empty matches. You could fix this quite easily by calling `en.split()` instead.

But perhaps you could use this different approach using a regular expression (and now there is no need to remove the punctuation first):

```
import re
print len(re.findall(r'\w+', line))
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/3q3KT)

Answer (score 8):

You can use [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/):

```
import nltk
en = "i ccc bcc the a of the abc ccc dd on aaa 28 abc 19 "
print(len(nltk.word_tokenize(en)))
```

Output:

```
15
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the regex `\w+` it is much faster to use `\b` for counting words, like so:

```
import re
_re_word_boundaries = re.compile(r'\b')

def num_words(line):
    return len(_re_word_boundaries.findall(line)) >> 1
```

Note that we have to halve the number because `\b` matches at both the beginning and the end of a word. Unfortunately, unlike egrep, Python does not support matching at only the beginning or the end.

If you have very long lines and are concerned about memory, using an iterator may be a better solution:

```
def num_words(line):
    return sum(1 for word in _re_word_boundaries.finditer(line)) >> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The len function counts the length of the variable, which in this case, is the length of the string, which is 30 characters. To count words, you'll need to split the string on whitespace, and then count the number of items which are returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():

# get the user msg
    print "this program tells you how many words are in your sentence."
    message = raw_input("Enter message: ")

    wrdcount = 0
    for i in message.split():
        eawrdlen = len(i) / len(i)
        wrdcount = wrdcount + eawrdlen
    print wrdcount


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the introductory example in the docs for [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects).  That shows how to find individual words in a sentence.